# TypeScript breakpoints not connecting

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I have a tsconfig.json with the following content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "../sdk_webroot/js",
        "rootDir": "js",
        "sourceRoot": "/js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "vendor"
    ]
}
```

I set up WebStorm with JavaScript debugging and connected `/sdk_webroot/js` to the correct directory on the web server. Nevertheless, breakpoints set in TypeScript never connect (e.g. don't work and don't get the ticker on the red not), while breakpoints set in JavaScript set within the `sdk_webroot` directory work just fine.

I've spent a coupe hours messing with sourceMappingURL and Googling an answer, to no avail. Chrome doesn't seem to load the .map files either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @Downvoters, care to elaborate?

Comment: most probably you have to set up Remote URL mappings in your javascript debug run configuration; i'd suggest creating a support ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by doing this:

```
    "outDir": "../sdk_webroot/js",
    "rootDir": "/js",
    "sourceRoot": "/../sdk/js"
```

Apparently sourceRoot ends up in the .map files, and being in a subdir, no longer points to the actual .ts files. Interestingly WebStorm was able to correctly link the sources, but not the breakpoints. Bummer.